# Модальные окна + ajax запросы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, я раньше писал на php и с ajax/jquery сталкивался не так часто. Сейчас встала потребность в более-менее современном интерфейсе для приложения. Я нашел пример, как у меня примерно будет выглядеть моя часть интерфейса с обработкой пользователей, вот ссылка:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-snipp-for-datatable

Но я не могу понять несколько вещей:

1. Как с помощью такого модального окна отправить данные. Я так понимаю что нужно как-то при ВЫВОДЕ модального окна привязывать к нему такие параметры как user_id к примеру, чтобы потом отправлять на нужный скрипт.
2. Как в самом модальном окне, в случае ошибки выводить, собственно, эту ошибку, если она пришла от целевого скрипта. Получается в самом модальном окне должен быть блок для отображения ошибки и ответ от скрипта по ajax помещается в это блок? И как в случае успешного ответа отобразить НОВОЕ модальное окно с сообщением об успешной операции.

В общем такой вот сумбур. Буду рад если подскажете что с этим делать. Спасибо.

Comment: Про второе, то как вы хотите выводить ошибки это ваше дело, оба варианта можно сделать, но чаще выводят ошибку по месту, т.е. в том же модальном окне. Ну а 1 утверждение верное. Вопрос про: что с этим делать, не понятен. Программировать?

Comment: Мне бы, наверное, какой-нибудь простой пример не помешал, потому что так трудно разобраться.

Comment: По ссылке которую вы скинули уже есть пример. Просто в модальном окне по клику на кнопку Отправить, делаете ajax запрос. Если ответ удачный закрываете окно, и может что-то пишете как успешно, если не удачный то выводите в окно сообщение об ошибке. В интернете всех ответов на вопросы подобны вашему. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо, я вообще имел в виду пример того, как связать данные пользователя с модальным окном, чтобы потом отправить запрос с этими данными.

Comment: Тоже много вариаций есть, можно например записывать в элемент модального окна невидимые поля с нужными вашими данными на событие клика. Самый простой для вас способ

Comment: А можно пример, потому что я не представляю как можно было бы привязывать поля к модальному окну, чтобы потом их отправить.

Comment: У вас как модальное окно устроено? Я же не знаю. Оно уже может лежать в DOM'е и вы его можете заполнять, или вы создаете его отдельно при клике. Оба варианты просты тем, что вы закидываете в них `<input type"hidden" id="row_id" value="100500" />`. И при клике по какой-то кнопке привязываете этому идентификатору ваш нужный id. Какой ещё вам нужен пример? `$('#row_id').val('MY_ID')` - такой?

Comment: Ну я же привел ссылку, там с помощью средств бутстрапа создается модальное окно. Мне не ясно как при таком подходе данные добавлять в форму. Нужен свой обработчик получается?

Comment: Вы можете привести код, как это сделано у вас? Вариантов создания модального окна и передачи данных может быть много. И на этом сайте уже неоднократно обсуждалось то как это можно сделать.

Comment: У я пока отталкиваюсь от примера, там модальное окно вызывается так data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" , это атрибуты кнопки.

Comment: Научитесь открывать окно с помощью javascript, а не тегом html, и дальше у вас все получится. Так реализация открытия нужна лишь для того, чтобы выводить статические окна, в которые ничего не нужно передавать.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, ладно спасибо. Буду разбираться.